# 404 when Serving Static Files Owned By Another User From /opt

Tags: nginx

OS = Debian 11

I have edited default *nginx* (version 1.18.0, installed from Debian repository) config as below:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    root /var/www/html;

    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name _;

    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    location /torrent/ {
            autoindex on;
            alias /opt/docker/qbittorrent/downloads;
    }
}
```

to serve my downloaded files with *qbittorent* docker container on HTTP protocol. However, I get a *404 Not Found* error when I visit either `/torrent/` or `/torrent/some_folder/some_name.some_extension`.

If important, these have `rw-r--r--` permission and are owned by `docker_qbit:docker` though the web server is installed by a *sudo*er.

Comment: I think I may be able to answer this but I need to understand the requirements a little better.
You mean for the files to have permission `rw-r--r--` or "644" with the Owner being "docker_qbit" and the Group being "docker"?
I may be wrong, but if this is correct then I think the solution would be to add "nginx" user to the "docker" Group.

Comment: @Cnasp Yes, all are correct.

Comment: Did you check the permission of `/opt/docker/qbittorrent/downloads`, `/opt/docker/qbittorrent`, `/opt/docker`, `/opt` and `/`?

Comment: @PothiKalimuthu Except the last one (i.e., root `/`) which I don't know what its permission is, they are all 755; however, the last but two are owned by `root:root`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to all. The problem was omitted trailing `/` after the address in the `alias` directive.

Answer (score 0):

What is happening is that the NGINX user doesn't have permission to traverse the directory you have specified in your alias.

Your requirements indicate we cannot change the permissions on the target directory.

The only solution I see would be to add the main `nginx` (www-data) user to the `docker` group. That way the webserver should be able to access the specified directory without changing its permission.

If the default nginx user on Debian 11 is `www-data`.

Assuming that to be the case, the command to do this would look like this:

```
usermod -a -G docker www-data
```

That command will modify the user "www-data" by adding them to group "docker".

To be sure what user is running nginx you could look at the output of this command:

```
ps -eo user,comm | grep nginx
```

Once complete you can reload nginx and see if the content is now available.

```
systemctl reload nginx
```

Comment: Thanks. The outputs of the last command are `root    nginx` and `www-data    nginx`. But the first command run with a *sudo*er says that `usermod: user 'nginx' does not exist`

Comment: So your "nginx" user is actually "www-data". I will update my answer for this.

Comment: Changed nginx user to match your system user. I hope this gets you going. Let me know! =)

Comment: Unfortunately, nothing changed with adding this user to the group.

Comment: Is there anything in `/var/log/nginx/error.log that may be useful?

Comment: Yeah! Thanks. It shows that the final problem is the omitted trailing `/` after the address in the `alias` command. Solved, thanks.